# When using swfobject, swf file ignores z-index

Tags: css, actionscript, flash, z-index, swfobject

I have this issue where if I append a swf file using SWFObject, it ignores my css rules for z-index. I have tried to set the parent container, the swf file, and everything around it; nothing seems to work for me. Has anyone ran into this issue and could give me some helpful advice?

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your using "transparent" wmode.

```
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent"; 
swfobject.embedSWF("file.swf", "id_name", "100", "100", "10.0.0",false,false,params);
```

Answer (score 2):

Z-index is ignored by Flash Player, you can't control it.  Here's a [quick overview with examples](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/placing-html-elements-over-a-flash-movie/).